# Classpath configuration for writing into a json file

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc, classloader, filewriter

In an eclipse project , I would like to create a json file and the file exists in the same project build and give its class path in the code so that the data will be stored in to that json file.

However if i try like below the data is not writing to the file

```
 try (Writer writer = new FileWriter("/src/test/java/operatorList.json"))   {
                Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create(); 
            gson.toJson(foo, writer); 
            writer.flush();
           writer.close();
        System.out.println("JSON :: "+gson.toJson(foo));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
  }
```

but when i change file location like below  it is working perfectly

```
try (Writer writer = new FileWriter("G://operatorList.json")) {
                Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create(); 
            gson.toJson(foo, writer); 
            writer.flush();
           writer.close();
        System.out.println("JSON :: "+gson.toJson(foo));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
}
```

please help on this for getting the file location in the same project

Answer (score 1):

Try using "src/test/java/operatorList.json" rather than using "/src/test/java/operatorList.json" as file name in FileWriter constructor. 
I tried with simple test with Java 8 compiler and it is working.

```
    java.io.FileWriter fileWriter = new java.io.FileWriter("src/test.txt");
    fileWriter.write("Test123");
    fileWriter.flush();
    fileWriter.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```